# To clean or not to clean $JBOSS_HOME/server/web/tmp directory?

Tags: jboss, jboss5.x

We have script that restarts JBoss.
Should we clean following directories in this script:

> $JBOSS_HOME/server/web/tmp
>   $JBOSS_HOME/server/web/work
>   $JBOSS_HOME/server/web/data

Or JBoss should clean all old files in these directories automatically?

Our clients complains that there are very old files in these directories.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9851652/jboss-as-7-how-to-clean-up-tmp

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't have experience with jboss 5, but in prior versions the contents of those directories sometimes got corrupted and had to be manually cleared.  So we added it to our restart script.  Haven't noticed any ill effects.

Comment: Do you clean all of these directories?

Comment: Can you show me part of the "restart script" where you clean the directories?

Answer (score 2):

JBoss 5 dies not automatically clean these folders. Whenever I see issues with error deploying the ear file, I first clean up the rver/all/tmp folder. I am not sure under what circumstances it really helps, but I have not seen any ill effects of deleting the files there. Just make sure that jboss server is shutdown before you delete the contents.