# clean JBoss 7 tmp using java code

Tags: java, jboss7.x, jmx

i want  to clean the jboss 7 tmp folder using java code

is there a way to do this?
it should be use JMX?
please help me i want to this code
and thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to get  the file structure like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9851652/jboss-as-7-how-to-clean-up-tmp) and have to `clean/delete` internal files in  that `temp` folder.

[JBoss AS 7: How to clean up tmp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9851652/jboss-as-7-how-to-clean-up-tmp)

But please read the recommendation there.

Comment: What I'm saying is connect to that directory through code and clear it ..not manually :)

Answer (score 1):

This would give you the temp directory path which you can use in your java program create a file instance and carry out the operation.

```
System.getProperty("jboss.server.temp.dir");
```