# How to delete wildfly tmp folder

Tags: jboss, wildfly

Hy,

I want delete the tmp folder when I restart the Wildfly service.
Do I modify the standalone.xml or another file ?

Sam

Comment: What is the reason you want to delete it?

Comment: The TMP directory becomes too large and causes a error when I restart Wildfly service.

Comment: It should be getting cleaned up on it's own is why I asked. Unless your application is using it to store data. What version of WildFly?

Comment: I use Wildfly 8.1.0

Comment: You shouldn't need to delete anything in the tmp directory. When you shutdown the server what is left in there?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem with modifying the standalone.conf.bat file.

I added : `rmdir %JBOSS_HOME%\standalone\tmp /s /q`

It's a temporary solving. If someone have a better idea ?

Answer (score 0):

we basically do the same thing as your answer. I searched and found that jboss7 had some flags you could use for vfs lifecycle, maybe they still exist for WFLY?

see [JBoss AS 7: How to clean up tmp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9851652/jboss-as-7-how-to-clean-up-tmp)